# Only allow numbers, decimals, negative

Tags: jquery, keypress

I have this code that only permits numbers to be entered in an input field on keypress()

```
if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
    return false;
}
```

How can I also allow decimals, and minus keypress?

Comment: By adding the values corresponding to decumal, plus etc. Google what .which actually is and it should become clear to you.

Comment: I did before posting this question, but the jQuery page doesn't explain much.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution, but I recommend to use mask plugin, for example: [jQuery-Mask-Plugin](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

```js
$("#id").keypress(function(e){
  if (e.which != 46 && e.which != 45 && e.which != 46 &&
      !(e.which >= 48 && e.which <= 57)) {
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="id" />
```

Comment: It doesn't check for multiple negative signs. I am able to enter `-2-24-2`. This is an invalid number.

Comment: @MilanChheda This is a specific solution, for that reason I recommend to use mask plugin

Answer (score 3):

```
 $('.DecimalNumberWithNegative').keypress(function (event) {
        NumberPostiveNegativeWithDecimal(event, this)
    });
 $('.DecimalNumberWithNegative').keyup(function (event) {
         ReplaceNegative(event, this); 
    });

function NumberPostiveNegativeWithDecimal(evt, element) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if (
        (charCode != 45 || $(element).val().indexOf('-') != -1) &&
        (charCode != 46 || $(element).val().indexOf('.') != -1) &&
        (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        evt.preventDefault();
    return true; 
}

function ReplaceNegative(event, element) { 
    var $$this = $(element).val();
    //alert($$this);
    var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode == 189 && $$this.indexOf('-') > 0) {
        value = $$this.replace('-', '');
        $(element).val(value);
        event.preventDefault();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Could you add some comments to explain what the advantages about the other answer are?

Comment: Other function its allowing the '-' signature any where on the textbox ,'-' signature first occurance of the number then only its means a negative number

Answer (score 2):

## Allow numbers, decimals, negative

This solution prevents double *minuses* or *dots*.

Just add **number** to input class.

```
$("input.number").on('keypress', function(e) {
    var caret = e.target.selectionStart;
    var nowStr = $(this).val().substr(0, caret) + String.fromCharCode(e.which) + $(this).val().substr(caret);
    if (!$.isNumeric(nowStr)) e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. You saved my time, I was trying to solve this issue for a day. But seems like it will restrict when enter "-" at start. But can add negative symbol at already existing number

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working demo that checks whether the number is valid or not and also doesn't allow multiple signs:

```js
$("#num").on('keyup', function() {
  if ($.isNumeric($(this).val())) {
    console.log('Valid!');
  } else {
    console.log('Invalid!');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id="num" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an editable cell in a table, you can use the following keypress function

```
function validate(e) {  
     var caret = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startOffset;
       var data =e.target.textContent
       var newData = data.substr(0, caret) + String.fromCharCode(e.which) 
                     +data.substr(caret);
      if (!$.isNumeric(newData)) {
    if (newData == "." || newData == "-")
        return true;
    e.preventDefault();
}
    }
```

Or you can use

```
 function validate(evnt) {
       var caret = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startOffset;
       var charC = (evnt.which) ? evnt.which : evnt.keyCode;
       var data =evnt.target.textContent
       if (charC == 46) {
          if (data.indexOf('.') === -1) {
             return true;
          } else {
             evnt.preventDefault();
          }
       }
       else if (charC == 45) {
          if (data.indexOf('-') === -1) {
             return true;
          } else if (caret >0) {
             evnt.preventDefault();
          } else {
             evnt.preventDefault();
          }
       } else {
          if (charC > 31 && (charC < 48 || charC > 57))
             evnt.preventDefault();
        }
      return true;
    }
```