# Allow positive and negative values in Jquery keypress validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**jquery**

```
$(".numeric").bind("keypress", function (e) {
        var keyCode = e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode
        var ret = ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || specialKeys.indexOf(keyCode) != -1);
        return ret;
    });
```

**Html**

```
<input type="text" class="numeric" id ="txt"/>
```

Here the code is working fine to validate numeric values with decimal.

But I want negative values to be included in the validation like -1.23,-2.23,-37.856,etc.

Note: The - symbol should appear only at the beginning and should be optional.

Comment: FYI, jQuery `bind` is deprecated in favor of `on`

Comment: Question marked as duplicate doesn't answer whats needed here. This link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29977092/only-allow-numbers-decimals-negative) does allow multiple minus sign, and hence doesn't answer this question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an extremely simple demo to help you out:

```js
$("#num").on('keyup', function() {
  if ($.isNumeric($(this).val())) {
    console.log('Valid!');
  } else {
    console.log('Invalid!');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id="num" />
```